# Passing derived type as argument to abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I was wondering if it is possible to implement a similar signature to the below code in c#:

```
public abstract class baseClass
{
    public abstract float function(derivedType a, derivedType b);
}

public class derived: baseClass
{
    public override float function(derived a, derived b)
    {
        return something to do with a and b;
    }
}
```

Hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to do from that, cheers.

Edit: I tried the below with no success, hopefully it might also clarify what I'm trying to do:

```
public abstract class baseClass
{
    public abstract float function<T>(T a, T b) where T:baseClass;
}

public class derived: baseClass
{
    public override float function<derived>(derived a, derived b)
    {
        return a.value + b.value;
    }

    public float value;
}
```

Apparently derived doesn't contain a definition for 'value' according to visual studio.

Edit, SOLUTION:

```
public abstract class baseClass<T> where T: baseClass<T>
{
    public abstract float function(T a, T b);
}

public class derived : baseClass<derived>
{
    public override float function(derived a, derived b)
    {
        return a.value + b.value;
    }

    public float value;
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help :)

Comment: It's not clear. What is `derivedType`?

Comment: It is whatever type inherits from baseClass, in this case the class 'derived'

Comment: You can make a generic method where the type constraint is that T is of type `baseClass`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Simply use `baseClass` as argument's type

Comment: Both good suggestions, see my edit. Using baseClass as arguments type doesn't help as I need access to methods within the derived class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly what you are looking for, all you have to do is this:

```
public abstract class baseClass<T> where T : baseClass<T>
{
    public abstract float Foo(T a, T b);
}

public class derived : baseClass<derived>
{
    public override float Foo(derived a, derived b)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public float value;
}
```

Comment: why do you need the generic type `<T>` on the method signature?

Comment: Thanks, you're post pointed me in the right direction, see my solution in edit. Cheers.

Comment: Good point you don't.  I was working with his code as a base, and didn't think to remove that.  It's already defined as the class level.