# Generic methods and type casting

Tags: c#, generics, generic-method

I read the following question (and I would solve it the same way as the given answer): [Passing derived type as argument to abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806119/passing-derived-type-as-argument-to-abstract-class/39806281#39806281)

But why is it not able to find the `value` attribute from the derived class? even if I add a type cast it is not possible:

```
public abstract class baseClass
{
    public abstract float function<T>(T a, T b) where T:baseClass;
}

public class derived: baseClass
{
    public override float function<derived>(derived a, derived b)
    {
        // Here value is not found
        return a.value + b.value;
    }

    public float value;
}
```

Example with type cast is also not working (and the advice redundant type cast is shown):

```
public abstract class baseClass
{
    public abstract float function<T>(T a, T b) where T:baseClass;
}

public class derived: baseClass
{
    public override float function<derived>(derived a, derived b)
    {
        // Here value is not found even with type cast
        return ((derived)a).value + ((derived)b).value;
    }

    public float value;
}
```

Comment: Example with type cast is working - it's naming issue. Rename generic type parameter back to `T`, then you can cast to `derived`.

Comment: @2kay thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're declaring the generic type parameter on the method. The compiler doesn't understand that this should be of the `derived` type. All it knows it that you've introduced a new generic type parameter.

What you want is called [F-bound polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification), where the type parameter is of the implementing class, defined recursively:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract float Function(T a, T b);
}

public class Derived : BaseClass<Derived>
{
    public override float Function(Derived a, Derived b)
    {
        return a.Value + b.Value;
    }

    public float Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't it know the type when I add it explicite?

Comment: @KevinWallis The compiler isn't treating `derived` as the `derived` type you've created. From it's perspective, it's a *generic type parameter* called `derived`, since that is how `BaseClass` declares `Function`, with two abstract type `T` parameters.